# WPF C# Pass Rich Text Editor from class to Main Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I need some help on passing a value from one class to the main window. The Main Window is up and running in the background, so a new instance is not needed (I don't think). The Main Window is a tab control using DevExpress. One the tab, I have a button. When the button is pressed, it opens a new window. I type text into the new window, check the spelling, and press the Return Data button. When I press the Return Data button, I want the text in the Rich Text Editor to pass to the Main Window in a textbox.

Here's the code I have now, but for some reason I keep getting that annoying error "object not set to an instance of an object". Can you help?

```
public MainWindow Main = null;

private void ReturnData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var val = RichEditControl1.Text;
        Main.TbNoteText.Text = val;
        Close();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What's the MainWindow called? I.e., the name of it's View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting a null ptr exception is that you are trying to access `Main` when it is never set (the declaration is being set to null).

You can get an instance of the `MainWindow` like this:

```
private void ReturnData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mainWindow = (MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow;
    var val = RichEditControl1.Text;

    mainWindow.TbNoteText.Text = val;
    Close();
}
```

Comment: This was on the right path. I made some very minor changes, but it worked. Thank you.

Comment: MainWindow = (MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow;